# 'fread' not compatible with leading/trailing whitespace?

Tags: r, whitespace, data.table, fread

I am trying to read a text file which has columns separated by space, in R. I tried using data.table since read.csv is taking long to read. However, the first column has leading whitespace and I am getting the following error in fread().
"Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch=' '"

The data format is similar to,

```
    45 36 46  
    45 67 35
```

Is there any way this can be read using fread() without reformatting the textile?

Comment: Is there a header row? Can you give the first few lines of the file?

Comment: No there is no header row.

Answer (score 0):

If you're under linux, try `fread("sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' testing.dat")`. The `sed` command will remove the leading blanks of every line in `testing.dat`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using `readLines`, but I am not sure about the speed.

```
require(data.table)

setwd("~")

in.df <- data.table(A = c(" a1"," b2"," c3"," d4"),
                    B = c(11,22,33,44))
in.df

write.table(in.df, file="testing.dat", quote = F,
            row.names = F, col.names = F)

dat <- paste(sub("^\\s+", "", readLines("testing.dat")), collapse = "\n")
dat

test.df <- fread(dat, stringsAsFactors = F)
test.df
```